# Angular2: Infinite route loop, browser crashing

Tags: angular, webpack, routes, angular2-routing, webpack-dev-server

When logging out of my application, there seems to be an infinite loop during the routing to my login page.  Everything seemed to be working fine until a couple days ago.  Could this possibly be due to a bug with Angular or WebPack?

**Here is some code example:**

Route in app.routing.ts:

```
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

Component function that routes to login component

```
logout() {
    this.authGuard.logout();
    this.portalsService.announceLoggedIn("");
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Everything seems to run fine right until the last line of logout() that routes to my login page (router.navigate).  Pretty sure its not an issue with my services.  All of the other routes are working perfectly fine too, this issue only seems to come on logout.

Here is another [thread on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14262) where a user was experiencing a similar issue. However he was using canActivate() and I am not so I am not sure if it is the same cause.  He provides an Plunker of the browser crashing so it might be useful to check it out as it is the exact same experience I am having on my browser. Careful tho, you browser will literally crash lol.

I've tested so far on Chrome and Edge, both are crashing upon logout.  Most of the time i have to use the task manager to shut them off.  Haven't tested on Mozilla yet as I am having an issue with my vendor.js bundle compilation, may be a related issue.  But it works perfectly fine on chrome and edge.

I am not sure what exactly the issue is as it is hard to debug since the browser crashes after the route.navigation function is hit.  Could possibly be a webpack/angular-cli compilation issue.  The route was working perfectly fine just last week.

additional info: running on VS2017 and IIS express

Any input or sharing of a similar experience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Like the browser itself just stops working and exits?

Comment: Yup most of the time the tab itself freezes and I am unable to exit it but the other tabs are working.  I have to go to the task manager and close the entire browser just to stop the tab from running.  Other times the entire browser itself freezes and I cant even switch to other tabs

Comment: Do you have commented the first two line to see which one is looping?

Comment: @Vega hi sorry I am not sure what you mean.  Do you mean i should comment out the first two lines ?

Comment: yes, I meant that, sorry

Comment: @Vega no problem, I appreciate you helping me out.  I commented them out, and there may be an issue with the second line.  I am testing it out right now, will come back with an update if I discover something.

Comment: navigate is the promise itself. So I think you can test If the navigate is successful or not by using these block of code. And get back to us what did you see on browser console.
this.router.navigate(['/login']).then(()=> console.log('navigated to login')).catch(()=> console.log('error navigated to login'))

Comment: @trungk18 thanks for your response.  I tried using the console.log but I am unable to get a message from it since the browser crashes before anything is logged.

Comment: So weird, seem it didn't get into navigate at all. What do you have on this.portalsService.announceLoggedIn("") ?

Answer (score 0):

I faces with a similar case, in my case the line: this.router.navigate(['/login'])
cause to recreate of another component, inside the ngOnInit hook of the component was a call to a service that invoke this.router.navigate(['/login']) in case of 401 server error,that cause to infinite loop and browser crashing.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem.

Had setup an guard which redirects to another page when not meeting a condition. Which also has the same guard therefore setting up loop and browser crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a wrongful parameter there:

```
this.router.navigate(  ['/login']  );
```

This should either be:

```
this.router.navigate(  ['login']  );
```

Or if you want to navigate by URL, just tell it so:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(  '/login'  );
```